# Failed to compile Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

Tags: reactjs

Tengo el siguiente código en `ReactJS`:

```
class LandingPage extends Component {
    state = {
        HomeSettings: [],
        loading: true
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        // Call api function
        console.log(getLanguage());

        this.fetchConfig();
    }
    ...
```

Después de ejecutar este código me aparece este error:

> Line 20:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

```
  18 |         loading: true
  19 |     };
> 20 |     componentDidMount() {
     |                         ^
  21 |         // Call api function
  22 |         console.log(getLanguage());
  23 |
```

Comment: No lo sé pero supongo: el punto y coma al cerrar las llaves de `state` es necesario?

Comment: Puedes dar un mejor formato a las últimas líneas. Es código o error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La sección :

```
state = {
    HomeSettings: [],
    loading: true
};
```

Debería de estar dentro de una función, y supongo que en esta ocasión debería de estar en el `constructor` de tu componente, así:

```
class LandingPage extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        // y aqui viene la inicializacion de state
        this.state={
            HomeSettings: [],
            loading: true
        };
    }
     componentDidMount() {
        // Call api function
        console.log(getLanguage());

        this.fetchConfig();
    }
    //y no olvides el render
    render(){
       return <div>mi contenido</div>
    }

}
```

Con eso tu problema debería de solucionarse.